# Conditional expectation - conditioning with independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have doubts about two related equalities involving conditional expectation:

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables; let $Z$ be independent on $X,Y$.

- Is $E[X \mid \beta Z + Y] = E[X \mid Y]$?
- Is $E[\alpha Z \mid \beta Z + Y] = E[\alpha Z \mid \beta Z] = \frac \alpha\beta Z$ ?

**Thoughts**

Intuitively, both seem correct, as $Z$ is independent on $X,Y$ and does not add information to $X$ (and conversely $Y$ does not add information to $Z$). It is also true that $$E[X \mid Z,Y] = E[X \mid Y]$$

but in this case I am conditioning on the sum of $Z$ and $Y$. How do the conclusions change?

Comment: No, neither of those equalities hold in general. Think of the case when $Y = X$ with probability $1$ for a quick counterexample. Intuitively, $Z$ is like additive noise, and so the estimates of $X$ given a noisy reading of $Y$, $\beta Z + Y$, cannot be the same as those given an exact reading $Y$. Also, your last equality should be $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z,Y] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid Y].$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you, I corrected the typo :) I see your point, but can't we somehow still take $Z$ out? Maybe by substituting it with it's mean?

Comment: Why? How is replacing $Z$ by its mean justified? 
Mathematically, it's easy to see that the two expectations are different. If you want a deeper reasoning, the data processing inequality in information theory comes to mind. This says that no matter what post processing you do, you fundamentally cannot improve your estimates from a (single) noisy sample to the level of estimation offered by a noiseless sample. This is directly applicable, as these conditional expectations are merely the minimium square error estimates given the realisation of $Y + \beta Z$.

Comment: If you're in the mood for some appeal to authority - if what you want is true in general, then we never have to worry about noise in any engineering system in the world that's based on linear estimates. Surely we engineers would have noticed that, right? :)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Yes, I agree with your point; clearly we can't get to the same accuracy as in the noiseless case. On the other hand, probably something can still be said, i.e. there is a way to express $E[X \mid \beta Z + Y]$ as a function of $E[X \mid Y]$ plus noise (as a function of $Z$). For example, if  $E[X \mid Y] = 0$, then I am pretty sure that also $E[X \mid \beta Z + Y] = 0$.